# Ordering by where one column is exactly the same value as another column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need to order by where one column is exactly the same value as another column. Is there any way at all to do this? If there is, please let me know. `ORDER BY wordMatch = wordCount`

```
SELECT * , 
( input LIKE  '% i %') + 
( input LIKE  '% love %' ) + 
( input LIKE  '% you %' ) AS wordMatch, 
( LENGTH( input ) - LENGTH( REPLACE( input,  ' ',  '' ) ) -1 ) AS wordCount
FROM allData
HAVING wordMatch > ( wordCount * 0.6666 ) 
AND wordCount > ( 3 * 0.6666 ) 
ORDER BY wordMatch = wordCount
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the closest matches first, then use `desc`:

```
order by (wordMatch = wordCount) desc
```

Or, you might also want the absolute value of the difference:

```
order by abs(wordMatch - wordCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this:

```
ORDER BY wordMatch = wordCount DESC , wordCount DESC
```